# Mantis summary for bug fixed, time taken to fix each bug per developer

Tags: bug-tracking, mantis

We use Mantis as a bug tracking system in our company.
I am aware of the bug lifecycle inside mantis.

I wanted to know if there is any way i can generate a SUMMARY of bugs that 
-- a developer has fixed
-- time needed to fix each bug
-- for a project

I am interested to generate a report for myself just to see if we can bubble up any patterns across project.

Thanks!